# When will the Youtube Data API quota apply?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have built a system that uploads to our YouTube channel through Youtube Data Api. However, because of the need for a large quota, I requested to increase the quota through the YouTube customer center, and two days ago, the contents were approved and the answer was that they would apply the quota. But we don't have time to wait. When will the quota be applied?

Comment: My experience anytime between 1 week and 3 months.  You just have to wait I would say if its not there by next week email them back.

Comment: what if we need it asap? they didn't told us it will take over 1 week. if there is no information about it, it will be understood as it will happen anytime soon. is there any contact point that we can ask shorten that time? it is matter of business.

Comment: This is a free API, You get what you pay for.   The only thing you can do is email them back